# Is " Had it not been him, it would be more complicated." more correct than " Had it not been him, it would've been more complicated."

Tags: conditional-constructions

Which statement would be more preferable

" Had it not been him, it would be more complicated."

or :

" Had it not been him, it would've been more complicated." ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement refers to the impact that "his involvement" makes on a future situation.

The second statement refers to the impact that "his involvement" made on a past situation.

So, imagining that "he" had been involved in a traffic accident, with the insurance still to be resolved, and he is able to facilitate things, **it would be more complicated without his involvement**.

If the insurance had already been resolved with his assistance, **it would have been more complicated without his involvement**.

It is simply a question of context, not of correctness or grammar.

Comment: Ronald....please tell...I think, in the first example, it should be: "If it was not him,it would be more complicated without his involvement."

Comment: @PrernaKrishna Your suggested sentence is NOT an improvement but a change. It is saying something different.

Comment: @PrernaKrishna The comments section can't be used for discussions on related issues. You need to phrase your thoughts as a separate question.

Comment: Actually I didn't understand the first example given by OP, therefore I asked you to explain it please.